# How to get cookie with POST request to another site, PHP

Tags: php, post, cookies, request, captcha

I am trying to solve this problem for last few days and I don't have a clue.
I need to send a request to another web site.
Since I am also using that site's captcha, I need to get cookie in order to successfully send my request.
This is my code.
How can I manage to save cookie the first time I send a request and also to set that cookie and send it along with my POST request to that web site?

Thank you for your answer, I know the question is basic but I can not combine anything.

```
$d = $_REQUEST["date"];
$t = $_REQUEST["table"];
$r = $_REQUEST["registration"];

$url = 'https://www.huo.hr/hrv/provjera-osiguranja/11/';

$data = array('date' => "$d", 'city' => "$t", 'reg1' => "$r", 'security_code' => 'ffff');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n", 
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($result === FALSE) { 
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo "<div style='overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;'>" . $result ."</div>";
}
```

Comment: for using cookie, you have to use curl instead of file_get_contents. btw why not recaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a "cookie jar" with cUrl and store the result of the cookie jar on your server to reference it later.

Something like:

```
$cookie_file = "/tmp/cookie/cookie1.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

Now, if you do the POST or GET requests to the other website, you can store it inside the cookie jar, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send your cookies to another website.

Comment: Please use english only so that everyone can follow the conversation. And this answer doesn't answer the question. She wants to store a cookie from the requested website and not send her own cookie. This is perfectly possible with cURL.

Comment: I / we used our native language due to better understanding what the goal of all idea is. Now, gathering cookie data are not really a point here (although, yes, that is a question), but sending cookie & session support "request" after comulating cURLed data to another website certainly is. And just FYI, I "answered" a question because my reps are to low to get into the story via comment, and ironicly, my answer to a whole idea - is correct. Her last line says.. "_and also to **set that cookie and SEND it** along with my POST request to that web site_" while we are chatting "literary".

Comment: You misunderstood the question. She wants to store the cookie from the requested website in order to use (send) that cookie for later requests to the same website. Again: This is possible with cURL.